# How to get block size and block mining time while using ganache and truffle

Tags: truffle, ganache, timestamp, linux

I am using truffle framework and Ganache (GUI) as emulator. 
I want to know the size of the generated block.
Also I want to know the time required to mine/generate/create a block after the command.
I need to use it for performance evaluation.
The version I am using are downloaded from the https://www.trufflesuite.com/ on Feb'2020
and Running in the VirtualBox LINUX OS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the navigation bar of the ganache GUI to know about the transactions and the blocks.

> I want to know the size of the generated block.

In Ganache each block contains only one transaction and you can easily check yourself by navigating to the Blocks section.

> Also I want to know the time required to mine/generate/create a block after the command.

Built in block/mine time is instant as the default setting on the Ganache GUI is of auto-mining but you can change that setting and provide the mining time.

I hope, this answers your query.